# SQL rollup two columns error

Tags: sql, rollup

i am having error in SQL saying:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
kolA varchar(255),
kolB varchar(255)
);

INSERT temp VALUES
('A','B'),
('B','B'),
('B','B'),
('A','B'),
(null,'B'),
('B','B');

select kolA,kolB,ilośc = COUNT(*) from temp
GROUP BY rollup(kolA,kolB);

DROP TABLE temp
```

i do not know why this error occurs, can someone tell me?

Comment: This runs for me fine in SQL Server. What are you using?

Comment: I am using Sql server Managment studio 2012. I opened again and now i do not see this error. I do not know why. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Against what DB - SQL SERVER 2014, SQL Azure, etc?

Comment: I opened again and now i do not see this error. I do not know why. Thanks for answer :)  I used 'New Query' in local database. SQL server 11.0.2100 i think that is the answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine against 2008 in a fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61dc9d/1

Comment: thanks !
 opened again and now i do not see this error. I do not know why. Weird thing